# Magento 2.1 - Get a collection including out of stock products

Tags: blocks, collection, product-collection, magento-2.1, out-of-stock

In a basic block I'm getting the featured products, however I only get the products that are in stock:

```
public function getProducts()
{
    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('featured', '1');

    $collection->getSelect()
        ->limit(8);

    return $collection;
}
```

How can I get the out of stock products (I guess those which stock_status=0 in cataloginventory_stock_status) as well? without changing "anything" in the backend configuration.

Comment: I tried this, it actually returns all products to me,  either in stock or out of stock, then in phtml you can filter by $_product->isSaleable(). Are you sure it returns only in stock products to you?

Comment: I don't know if it's because of something in my backend config, but yes, it definitely looks like I only get in stock products.

Comment: is this your custom module?

Comment: there is setting in admin configuration -> catalog -> inventory -> stock options -> Display Out of Stock Products . try that

Comment: You're right, it would probably work, but what about if that parameter has to be always NO, how can I still see those out of stock products in my module?

Comment: actually you should be able to, because I have that setting as NO and still able to fetch out of stock products by same query in custom module, I guess it can be any extension or some settings in your project which do not allow you to fetch out of stock product by this collection query.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,you can be get out of product in your collection whenever **Stock options -> Display Out of Stock Products  =  no**

Add below code to ***$collection***.

> ```
>     $cond = [
>         '{{table}}.use_config_manage_stock = 0 AND {{table}}.manage_stock=1 AND {{table}}.is_in_stock=1',
>         '{{table}}.use_config_manage_stock = 0 AND {{table}}.manage_stock=0'
>     ];
>
>         $cond[] = '{{table}}.use_config_manage_stock = 1';
>
>     $collection->joinField(
>         'inventory_in_stock',
>         'cataloginventory_stock_item',
>         'is_in_stock',
>         'product_id=entity_id',
>         '(' . join(') OR (', $cond) . ')'
>     );
> ```